# Views autocomplete with aggregation (and panels)

Tags: views, panels, ajax

I have panel that displays data from two custom content types, Funding and Partners. There are various attributes of Funding and Partners that I have exposed as filters.

There are two types of views I'm using to display data in the panel. The first type is simply a list of Funding instances. This is working just fine (I have the relationship setup between Funding and Partners, I'm using Content: title with the relationship, the autocomplete field points to this Content: title field, etc.).

The second type of view is giving me trouble. I'm using Aggregation to display the total number of Funding instances and the total amount of Funding, based on the exposed filters. This works just fine for most exposed filters, but it doesn't work for the Partner name. This is because I cannot include the Partner name in the list of fields and still get the aggregation behavior I want (including the Content: Type with the relationship gives me a list of funding, not the totals). Of course, when I remove the Partner name I no longer have to field to point the autocomplete exposed filter to.

Answer (score 0):

So the way to address this is actually easy, so sorry for having posted it.

In case anyone else is having this issue...in the panel, instead of using the exposed filters for the view with aggregation, I used the exposed filters for the view that just provided a list of Funding instances.

Then, in the settings for the view with aggregation there is no need to use autocomplete (just use Contains) - because I'm not displaying this exposed filter anymore.